# Python performance gains when destructing instances within a for loop

Tags: python, performance, loops, class, destructor

I am using a Python script to read in some ASCII file, manipulate their values and obtain an output. The calculation is done within a class instantiation, something like in pseudo-form

```
def __init__(input)
  self.input = input
  self.output = function of input
```

The pseudocode, with the controversial part between question mark, is

```
open file
read lines
for each lines in file: 
    split line
    construct class instance with input from split-line values
    store instance.output in a help variable (list)
    ?? delete class instance ??
further processing of the help variable
etc
```

Is deleting the class instance an hindrance or an opportunity for saving time and memory? The size of the problem is big (short of 1 million lines).

It is clear to me that I'd rather be reading in from a binary file, but this is not workable at the moment. Also, I choose the class construct because of elegance and perhaps, as the script develops, I could harvest more benefits from encapsulation. However, I could give it up at this stage if suggested to do so.

Comment: from what i know of the garbage collector in python, once an object becomes unreachable it is garbage collected - if you redefine the constructed class with the same reference you cant reach the initial object and it gets garbage collected anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why write psuedo code, not just python? Anyway, in python deleting the class instance is pointless if you're just going to override the name with a new instance next loop. The interpreter will automatically delete an object in memory when no references are held for it.

So those two options take almost the same time (see below):

```
from collections import UserList

def with_del():
    for i in range(10000):
        x = UserList([i])
        del x

def without_del():
    for i in range(10000):
        x = UserList([i])

%timeit with_del()
8.19 ms ± 188 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit without_del()
8.04 ms ± 92.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

The `with_del` probably takes slightly longer since there is an additional byte code instruction to run.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why write psuedo code, not just python? Just being in a hurry and away from my source code.

Answer (score 2):

Python automatically destructs an instance for you when there is no more reference to it as part of the garbage collection process so you should not do it yourself unless you actually want the instance deleted when there are still references to it.

In your case, new instances get created with every iteration, and since you are storing only the output derived from the instances, rather than the instances themselves, to a list, you aren't keeping any references to the old instances in the next iteration, so the garbage collection process will destruct the instances for you in an efficient manner so you don't have to worry about doing it yourself. Doing it yourself would actually be slower since you would be using Python code for the deletion, rather than using garbage collection, which is implemented purely in C.